# How to achieve alternate table in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, structure, alternate

[image]

I want to develop on SSRS reports for a student.

My layout is like this.

```
Table 1                                          Table 2
----------                                       --------
Semester 1                                       Semester 2

Cousercode  CourseName       Grade               Cousercode  CourseName       Grade

FT          Field Theory      B                   MA           Maths 1          A  
CS          Control Systems   A                   CS           Computer         C

Table 3                                          Table 4
----------                                       --------
Semester 3                                       Semester 4

Cousercode  CourseName       Grade               Cousercode  CourseName       Grade

ED          Electronics       B                   MA           Maths 2          A  
CS          Control Systems2  A                   CS           Computer         C
```

I don't know how to start, I know something about SSRS 2008. But not able to achieve the above layout structure. That table will grow depending on semesters. If there are 10 semesters means we have to show 10 tables. If it is 5 means then 5 tables and so on.

I have only one dataset and that will contain all the information about the semester for a particular student.

Here is the prototype of my layout

Here is my sample data

```
RBD-R000225 Humooda Ali Mohamed Husain AlHammadi    BSc IEM Semester 1 2013-14  Working with the Public and Media in Emergencies    E3.2.5  Register    NULL    NULL
RBD-R000225 Humooda Ali Mohamed Husain AlHammadi    BSc IEM Semester 1 2013-14  Working with the Public and Media in Emergencies    E3.2.5  Register    NULL    NULL
RBD-R000225 Humooda Ali Mohamed Husain AlHammadi    BSc IEM Semester 1 2013-14  Working with the Public and Media in Emergencies    E3.2.5  Register    NULL    NULL
RBD-R000225 Humooda Ali Mohamed Husain AlHammadi    BSc IEM Semester 1 2013-14  Working with the Public and Media in Emergencies    E3.2.5  Register    NULL    NULL
RBD-R000225 Humooda Ali Mohamed Husain AlHammadi    BSc IEM Semester 1 2013-14  Planning for Recovery from a CBRN attack    E3.2.4  WithDraw    NULL    NULL
RBD-R000225 Humooda Ali Mohamed Husain AlHammadi    BSc IEM Semester 1 2013-14  Planning for Recovery from a CBRN attack    E3.2.4  WithDraw    NULL    NULL
RBD-R000225 Humooda Ali Mohamed Husain AlHammadi    BSc IEM Semester 1 2013-14  Planning for Recovery from a CBRN attack    E3.2.4  Register    NULL    NULL
RBD-R000225 Humooda Ali Mohamed Husain AlHammadi    BSc IEM Semester 1 2013-14  Planning for Recovery from a CBRN attack    E3.2.4  Register    NULL    NULL
RBD-R000225 Humooda Ali Mohamed Husain AlHammadi    BSc IEM Semester 1 2013-14  Public Safety at Festivals and Mass Gatherings  E3.2.3  Not Required    NULL    NULL
RBD-R000225 Humooda Ali Mohamed Husain AlHammadi    BSc IEM Semester 1 2013-14  Public Safety at Festivals and Mass Gatherings  E3.2.3  Not Required    NULL    NULL
```

[image]

Comment: In order to achieve this you will need to create a multi-column report.

Comment: I think you've shown a clear idea of the final results, but what does your underlying data look like? Can you post a few rows of sample data that show what your Dataset looks like?

Comment: Ian, Above is the sample data

Comment: lrb, Do u have any idea how to do this as Multicolumn

Answer (score 0):

You have three problems: layout of the tables, getting the right data to the right tables and showing/hiding the tables. The below solution should work, although I haven't tested it.

**Layout:**
Use rectangle objects to keep each row of tables laid out as you need them. Note, you will have to drag the tables into the rectangle, drawing a rectangle around them will just draw one in front.

**Filtering:**
To make things easier I would recommend either changing the dataset or adding a calculated field which contains the semester number as an integer value. Assume I have added one to your dataset named *SemesterNum*.

In the *Tablix Properties* menu for the first table, access the *Filters* menu. *Add* a new filter and set the *expression* to be the SemesterNum field, the *operator* '=' and the *value* '1'. This will filter the data to show only semester 1 in this table.

Repeat for semesters 2 and 10, changing the *value* to be the semester number.

**Showing/Hiding:**
This is similar to Filtering. In the *Tablix Properties* menu for the first table, access the *Visibility* menu.

Set the *expression* to be =IIF(Count(Fields!SemesterNum.Value) > 0, true, false), *operator* '=' and the *value* true.

Place the same expression in all the tables.